# MS-Access - Query users from two tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a table named **All users** which holds all users and the sum of their access to a system. And two more tables from which I made the one with all the users, which are basically scattered over the two tables.

The problem with my **All users** table is that it doesn't have the **Name** column that corresponds with the **User**.

**tbl_sbc**

```
Users Name
Foo  John
```

**Users JDF**

```
Users Name
Bar  Andrew
```

**All Users**

```
Users
Foo
Bar
```

and I want the query to crossmatch the users on the all users table and retrieve their name which can be in one of the two other tables.

I tried doing

```
SELECT [Users], [Name] ,Sum([Access]) AS Total
FROM (Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from tbl_sbc
Union 
Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from [Users JDF])
GROUP BY [Users]
ORDER BY [users] DESC;
```

But I get `Your query does not include the specified expression [Name] as part of an aggregate function`
but without the [Name] it works fine

Comment: Selects with aggregate functions have to have all non aggregate columns in the group by

Comment: Thanks Doug, that solved

Comment: Hook me up with an answer mark :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this

```
 SELECT [Users], [Name] ,Sum([Access]) AS Total
 FROM (Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from tbl_sbc
 Union 
 Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from [Users JDF])
 GROUP BY [Users]
 ORDER BY [users] DESC;
```

AND Turn into this

```
 SELECT [Users], [Name] ,Sum([Access]) AS Total
 FROM (Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from tbl_sbc
 GROUP BY [Users], [Name]
 Union 
 Select [Users], [Name] , [Access] from [Users JDF])
 GROUP BY [Users]
 ORDER BY [users] DESC;
```